# Add Git to Existing PhpStorm Project Subfolder

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I've had a look around and can't seem to find an answer to this particular conundrum (which would make sense otherwise I wouldn't be here asking about it!) or at least if there has been one I haven't understood it.

I've created a project in PhpStorm, "Web server is on remote host, files are accessible by FTP/SFTP/FTPS", and I've been making changes to that with no problem. The structure of this project is as follows:

```
\Project Root
    \
    \ Subfolder A
        \ Contents A
    \
    \ Site
        \ Site stuff
    \
    \ Subfolder B
        \ Contents B
```

Now, I've got this like that because although the main files I'm working on are in `Site`, I occasionally need to tweak some stuff in the other subfolders.

Saving the project uploads the files without problem.

The thing I'm now having a problem with is that `Site` is under version control on the server using Git. I can log on to the server and do some Git stuff there (although I'm not too familiar with Git) but when I try to pull some changes that have been committed to the repo (that's upstream, yeah?) there is a merge conflict. Because I'm so new at this, I'd rather not try to resolve the conflicts through the command line using `vimdiff`.

Is there a way I can set up Git through PhpStorm to only act on that specific folder, pulling the changes from the remote repo (hosted on another server from this project), merging and resolving conflicts within PhpStorm, and then uploading the files in such a way that on the server the project shows as up to date with the current branch?

I've thought about grabbing the `.git` directory from the server via SFTP and plonking that in the `Site` folder like it is up there but I'm not sure that would work. I would also think PhpStorm has a good reason for not doing this in the first place.

**EDIT:** For a bit of clarification, `Site` is dirty. I don't want to commit those changes until I'm happy with them but I still need them to be there for now. I tried stashing, pulling, then applying but that's when I get the merge conflict error, and I want to resolve these conflicts within PhpStorm.

Comment: If the `Site` folder is the only thing under version control, then only this folder would be managed by Git.  You don't need to worry about other files/folders commingling with your VCS process.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm not worried about them mingling with the VCS, I just need to find out a way to get PhpStorm to recognise that `Site` is actually under VCS on the server and know where the repo is to pull the changes so I can merge and resolve the conflicts within PhpStorm itself. If that makes any sense :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, so I figured I'd be daring and try to ignore PhpStorm refusing to touch a `.git` folder. This is a long way round but here's what I did:

1. Open the project
2. Select `VCS` -> `Enable Version Control Integration`
3. Select `Git` as the VCS for the project root

This creates a `.git` folder in your project root. Since we don't want the root under VCS but one of the subfolders, we can:

4. Open `Preferences`
5. Select `Version Control` in the left hand pane
6. Select the project in the right hand pane and click the edit pencil
7. In the resulting dialog, edit the `Directory` entry to the subfolder you want to use Git with and click `OK`
8. `Apply` and `OK`

This will throw an error in the log moaning that the directory "is registered as a Git root, but no Git repos were found there." This is fine as we are going to add it ourselves.

9. Close PhpStorm
10. Open your favourite FTP program and grab the `.git` from the server
11. Plonk it in the directory you chose earlier (so `Project Root/Site` or whatever)

You can delete the `.git` folder PhpStorm created under your Project root because we don't need it anymore; it will use the one we just copied over.

There may be some extra setup to tweak. I access the Git repo with keys so you might have to add authorized keys to your git user on the repo.

You *can* just jump straight to Step 6 and add the directory straight there. I'm guessing it does the same thing.

But yes, now I can manage the project using Git and do my merges and things through PhpStorm instead of the command line on the server! :D

Comment: Can you explain "Open your favourite FTP program and grab the .git from the server"? Do you mean from github?

Comment: @Revious, if you're using GitHub, then yes, you can download the .git folder from GitHub. I think the easiest way might be to clone the GitHub repo to another directory and then manually copy the `.git` directory to where you need it (Step 11 above). Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already stash your local changes, you can sync your local `Site` with the server by below steps:

1. Exit the merge conflict when you execute `git pull` by `git merge --abort`.
2. Keep the local version as remote repo by `git reset --hard origin/master`.

When you are ready to use your local changes, you can use `git stash pop`.

Comment: I don't want to add the other folders to the repo. The one is project specific and the other has its own repo. I only want to act on the `Site` folder by pulling and merging the changes from the repo associated to it on the server.

Comment: So the remote repo has other folders except `Site` folder, and you only need to pull changes from `Site` folder on the server?

Comment: Remote repo is only `Site`. The subfolders are not in the repo and I don't want them to be. I only mentioned them to illustrate that not the entire project is under version control but they are still in the PhpStorm project.

Comment: Thanks. This is essentially the steps I attempted but it's still via the command line and not attached to PhpStorm. I managed to work it out though (: